Python subprocess - OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: 'perl'
I have a Python script, which loops over an id list. Within a for loop, messages are downloaded from S3 bucket based on the particular id. Then a Perl script is called and the messages are decrypted one by one. The average size of a message is a few 100kB, not that big.
When run the script, only the first 2 messages decrypted successfully, and I got "OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: 'perl'" error after that.
Python script
from subprocess import run


for id_ in ids:
    # this function calls "s3.get_object" and returns "StreamingBody()" object
    # from the "StreamingBody()" object the message is get as response["Body"].read()
    # the message is "bytes" type
    message = get_message_from_s3(id_)

    # call a Perl script to decrypt the message
    command = ["perl", "decrypt_message.pl", "decrypt_message", message]
    output = run(command, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    ...

Perl script
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $function = shift;
my $message = shift;

print decrypt_message($message);


sub decrypt_message {
    my $message = shift;

    my $decrypted_message = '';
    ...
    # decrypt here
    ...
    return $decrypted_message;
}

The size of the first 2 successful messages is about 20kB.The size of the unsuccessful ones are as mentioned a few 100kB. Can it be the problem? How to handle this?

The allowed size of the  argument list (measured in total characters, not just the number of distinct arguments) is OS-dependent. See, for example, the chart at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/.

Most limits are well under a few hundred kilobytes in size. A few extend to one or two megabytes. Linux is unique, as far as I know, in having a dynamic limit based on the size of the available stack. (I think I've seen this mistakenly described as unlimited, which it may be in practice given enough memory.)

Just to improve myself, why my question got -1?

100KB is pretty excessive for a command line; a typical limit might be as small as 32-64KB, but this is very system-dependent.
Modify your script to take input from stdin instead:
my $message = do { local $/; <> };

then launch the process as
command = ["perl", "decrypt_message.pl", "decrypt_message"]
output = subprocess.run(command, input=message, check=True, capture_output=True)
output = output.decode("utf8") # or whatever encoding you prefer


Details on process argument and environment limits on Linux: https://serverfault.com/a/844666

Thank you, the solution to read the input from stdin works fine.

Python script
from subprocess import run
...


for id_ in ids:
    # this function calls "s3.get_object" and returns "StreamingBody()" object
    # from the "StreamingBody()" object the message is get as response["Body"].read()
    # the message is "bytes" type
    message = get_message_from_s3(id_)
    ...
    filename = "sample"
    try:
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(message)
    except IOError:
        logger.error("Can not create %s file", filename)

    # call a Perl script to decrypt the message
    command = ["perl", "decrypt_message.pl", "decrypt_message", filename]
    output = run(command, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    ...
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except IOError:
        logger.error("Can not delete %s file", filename)
    ...

Perl script
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $function = shift;
my $filename = shift;

my $message;
open(my $fh, "<:raw", $filename) or die("Cannot open $filename: $!");
while(read($fh, my $buffer, 1024)) {
    $message .= $buffer;
}
close($fh);

print decrypt_message($message);


sub decrypt_message {
    my $message = shift;

    my $decrypted_message = '';
    ...
    # decrypt here
    ...
    return $decrypted_message;
}


I have decided to go this way. Write out the samples and read them from Perl script.
